# Is there any way to get Firebase Auth User UID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am looking to fetch Auth User(s) UID from Firebase via NodeJS or JavaScript API.
I have attached screenshot for it so that you will have idea what I am looking for.

[image]

Hope you can help me out with this.

Comment: Based on what do you want to retrieve it? authenticated user? user email? please, more details..

Comment: The UID of any user, or the authenticated one?

Comment: Basically, I need to generate token from UID by `Firebase.auth().createCustomToken(UID)`  to sign in user on firebase with the following function `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)`.

Comment: are you trying to get the uid on the server or on the client?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Auth data is asynchronous in Firebase 3. So you need to wait for the event and then you have access to the current logged in user's UID. You won't be able to get the others. It will get called when the app opens too.

You can also render your app only once receiving the event if you prefer, to avoid extra logic in there to determine if the event has fired yet.

You could also trigger route changes from here based on the presence of `user`, this combined with a check before loading a route is a solid way to ensure only the right people are viewing publicOnly or privateOnly pages.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User logged in already or has just logged in.
    console.log(user.uid);
  } else {
    // User not logged in or has just logged out.
  }
});
```

Within your app you can either save this user object, or get the current user at any time with `firebase.auth().currentUser`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged

Comment: But I need UID to login user.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, this will give you the UID of the logged in user. You can't get the UID of others.

Comment: This methods is not triggering at all for me.

Comment: This is not a solution to the problem

Comment: @PiyushBansal The (mostly misnamed) "uid" is any value, in this case probably coming from the user input, e.g. a login form. It's *not* the Firebase user uid. So in this case it's probably the username that you want to login with. See my longer answer below.

Answer (score 28):

if a user is logged in then the console.log will print out:

```
if (firebase.auth().currentUser !== null) 
        console.log("user id: " + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);
```

Comment: I was having an issue where this is not available immediately on page load. The callback method (onAuthStateChanged) worked for me though.

Answer (score 9):

**on server side you can use firebase admin sdk to get all user information :**

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
var serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://yourprojecturl.firebaseio.com",
});

admin.auth().listUsers().then(data=>{
    console.log(data.users)
})
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but I believe the accepted answer provides a correct answer to a *different* question; and although the [answer from Dipanjan Panja](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64686586/3029882) seems to answer the original question, the original poster clarified later in a reply with a different question:

> Basically, I need to generate token from UID by Firebase.auth().createCustomToken(UID) to sign in user on firebase with the following function firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).

Because the original question was clarified that the intent is to use
`createCustomToken` and `signInWithCustomToken`, I believe this is a question about using the **Firebase Admin SDK** or **Firebase Functions** (both server-side) to provide custom authentication, probably based on a *username* and password combination, rather than using an *email* address and password.

I also think there's some confusion over "uid" here, where in the code example below, it does NOT refer to the user's Firebase `uid`, but rather the `uid` indicated in the doc for [createCustomToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), which shows:

```
admin
  .auth()
  .createCustomToken(uid)
  .then((customToken) => {
    ...
```

In this case, the `uid` parameter on the `createCustomToken` call is not the Firebase `uid` field (which would not yet be known), thus providing a series of frustrating replies to the coder asking this question.

Instead, the `uid` here refers to *any arbitrary basis for logging in* for which this *custom* auth will support. (For example, it could also be an email address, social security number, employee number, anything...)

If you look *above* that short code block from the documentation page, you'll see that in this case `uid` was defined as:

```
const uid = 'some-uid';
```

Again, this could represent anything that the custom auth wanted it to be, but in this case, let's assume it's *username/userid* to be paired with a password.  So it could have a value of `'admin'` or `'appurist'` or `'123456'` or something else.

**Answer:** So in this case, this particular `uid` (misnamed) is probably coming *from user input*, on a login form, which is why it is available at (before) login time. If you know who is trying to log in, some Admin SDK code code then search all users for a matching field (stored on new user registration).

It seems all of this is to get around the fact that Firebase does **not** support a `signInWithUsernameAndPassword` (arbitrary userid/username) or even a `signInWithUidAndPassword` (Firebase UID). So we need Admin SDK workarounds, or Firebase Functions, and the serverless aspect of Firebase is seriously weakened.

For a 6-minute video on the topic of custom auth tokens, I strongly recommend Jen Person's YouTube video for Firebase here:
[Minting Custom Tokens with the Admin SDK for Node.js - Firecasts](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtYzHTXHBp0)

Answer (score 3):

As of now in Firebase console, there is no direct API to get a list of users, Auth User(s) UID.

But inside your Firebase database, you can maintain the User UID at user level. As below,

```
"users": {
  "user-1": {
    "uid": "abcd..",
    ....
  },
  "user-2": {
    "uid": "abcd..",
    ....
  },
  "user-3": {
    "uid": "abcd..",
    ....
  }
}
```

Then you can make a query and retrieve it whenever you need uid's.

 Hope this simple solution could help you!

Comment: Basically, I need to generate token from UID by `Firebase.auth().createCustomToken(UID)`  to sign in user on firebase with the following function `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token)`. Is there any other way to Sign In User on firebase ?

Comment: Firebase makes authentication easy. It has built-in functionality for email & password, and third-party providers such as Facebook, Twitter, GitHub, and Google. And with Firebase `custom Authentication API`, you can integrate with your existing login server too.

Comment: For more info go through these articles, hope this would help you,
[Link-1](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html) and 
[Link-2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/)

Answer (score 1):

From Firebase docs, use `Firebase.getAuth()`:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<YOUR-FIREBASE-APP>.firebaseio.com");
var authData = ref.getAuth();

if (authData) {
  console.log("Authenticated user with uid:", authData.uid);
}
```

*Source:*

- [Firebase.getAuth()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/getauth.html)

Comment: If I try it, `authdata.uid` belongs to which user? 

the problem is that I need UID to signin user on firebase and without authentication, how can I get the correct UID.

Comment: I believe this belongs to the currently authenticated user, this can be easily confirmed against the DB..

Answer (score 0):

This question is so old that the answers are outdated. the way to do access the user's UID is via the `user.uid` property in the user object when authenticate the user. Here is the code:

```
const handleSignUpWithGoogle = (isLoggedIn, navigation) => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, providerGoogle)
    .then((result) => {
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
      const token = credential.accessToken;
      const user = result.user;
      isLoggedIn = !isLoggedIn
      console.log(isLoggedIn, **user.uid**)
      navigation.navigate('Home')
      alert('Signing in with google succeeded')
    }).catch((error) => {
      // Handle Errors here.
      const errorCode = error.code;
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      const email = error.customData.email;
      const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
      // ...
    });
```