# Table design for storing user information, license, etc

Tags: ios, database, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently adding Google Firestore in my app so I can store user preferences, licenses, and other metadata. I have Google Authentication setup as well so I can track whatever the user is registered or not.

Not being a database/NoSQL expert, any design suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I need to store the following, and probably more later on:

- App installation / license (multiple platforms: iOS, macOS, etc.)
- Bought in-app purchases (for being able to restore them from another platform)
- User preferences, so they can be re-used on another platform and for backup purposes

I am thinking of this simple design:

```
/users (collection)
     |
     +-- {user_XXXXXX} <- what should be used here? e-mail? generated ID?
             |
             +--- app_licenses (collection)
                      |
                      + {license_XXX} <-- incremental id? auto-generated?
                      |    |
                      |    +-- platform : ios / macos / ...
                      |    +-- installation_id : device id ?
                      + {license_XXX} <--- incremental id? auto-generated?
                      |    +-- platform : ios / macos / ...
                      |    +-- installation_id : device id ?
                      |
             +--- iap_purchases (collection)
                      |
                      + {iap_XXX} <--- incremental id? auto-generated?
                           |
                           +-- name : unique identifier (title/name)
                           +-- transaction_id 
                           +-- date : purchase date
             +--- prefs
                    |
                    + fav_color : red / blue / ...
                    + another_pref : ....
```

Thank you!

Comment: A good document to securely design a Firestore database is available here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your design so far looks good to me.

**Regarding your root user level**: Do the user's your adding information for have to be logged in through firebase? If so, I would use the user's UID from firebase. It is guaranteed to be unique and can only be retrieved after authentication.
[Here's a stack overflow question concerning that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352772/is-there-any-way-to-get-firebase-auth-user-uid)

If you aren't necessarily storing users that are logged in through firebase, I would still use some kind of auto incremented id or GUID. Just make sure you avoid the possibility of duplicate id's being generated.

I would avoid using email because perhaps further down the road you might want to add multiple emails or even phone numbers as contact info.

**As for the licenses and in app purchases:** I'm not quite familiar with firestore, auto incrementing id's seems like only a SQL thing to me but  if you have that available to you, I think that's acceptable. GUID's would also work.

Comment: Yes, the user needs to be logged in, so I can use the UID from Firebase as you suggest.