# Why my snapshot return null, even there have values on Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with the code regarding the `snapshot` where I'm trying to get the `quantity` value in my Firebase Database. I have captured my database.

[image: console result]

and

[image: database]

```
 firebase.database().ref("mycart/"+uid+"/"+imguid).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log("uid="+uid); 
        console.log("imguid="+imguid); 
        console.log("snapshot.val()="+snapshot.val()); 
        if(snapshot.exists()){
           console.log("snapshot"+snapshot.key); 
        }
        console.log("snapshot doest exists"); 
    });
```

Comment: the snapshop.key return value=imguid

Comment: console.log(snapshot.val()) .. value is null

Comment: Are the rules set up wright for mycart?

Comment: firebase.database().ref('mycart/'+uid+"/"+imguid).update({
        image: imgurl,
        packageplace: place,
        price: total,
        quantity: parseInt(inputField.value, 10),
        uid:imguid
    }  rules set all is true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { 
 if (user) { 
 uid = user.uid;
 firebase.database().ref("mycart").child(uid).child(imguid).once("value").then(function(snapshot) { 
   if(snapshot.exists()){ 
       console.log("snapshot"+snapshot.key);
      } 
      console.log("snapshot doest exists"); 
    }); 
   }
  else{ } });
```

The `uid` that was returning null thus you got that error. Retrieving authentication data in firebase is asynchronous therefore if you want to use the `uid` to retrieve data from the database, then you need to add it under `onAuthStateChanged`

Comment: Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "null". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".. why? i got this

Comment: try `firebase.database().ref("mycart").child(uid).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
if(snapshot.exists()){
           console.log("snapshot"+snapshot.key); 
        }
        console.log("snapshot doest exists"); 
    });`

Comment: how are u retrieving the uid?

Comment: firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        uid = user.uid;
      
    }else{
       
    }

});

Comment: okay do this `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) { if (user) { uid = user.uid;firebase.database().ref("mycart").child(uid).child(imguid).once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
if(snapshot.exists()){
           console.log("snapshot"+snapshot.key); 
        }
        console.log("snapshot doest exists"); 
    }); }else{ } });`

Comment: its display  snapshot-LqFt_A6mvO2rJI7ScJo, i have try. its work when im try call snaphot.val().quantity

Comment: if i call snaphot.val() display [object Object].. i also have try to call quantity, its work.. its just i wonder what actual problem at my previous code

Comment: yes snapshot.val().quantity should give you the quantity now, its because the `uid` was null `onAuthStateChanged` is asynchronous so when you were retrieving data outside of this method, the `uid` was null since it was not yet retrieved. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38354441/7015400