# How can I get documents from Firestore for current user?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm trying do display data from Firestore database in my component.

This is my function:

```js
const getData = async () => {
    const data = [];

    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
      collection(databaseRef, "mK7DFNJgRAPmtvgrZh7X6AOj8cR2")
    );
    console.log(querySnapshot);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().Title);
      data.push({
        About: doc.data().About,
        Title: doc.data().Title,
        Who: doc.data().Who,
      });
    });
    setData(data);
  };
```

Collection ID = Current logged in User.
I want to display every document.
Everything works fine but insteed of passing hard-coded string here:

```js
      collection(databaseRef, "mK7DFNJgRAPmtvgrZh7X6AOj8cR2")
```

I would like to pass variable where I store my UID.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Maybe `getUser().currentUser.uid`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your user is logged in, you should be able to access their UID via `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352772/is-there-any-way-to-get-firebase-auth-user-uid)'s answers may be useful for more information on getting the current user's ID.

With that, you should be able to do:

```js
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
    collection(databaseRef, firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
);
```

to get the current user's documents.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser

Comment: I've added: `const auth = getAuth(); let UID = auth.currentUser.uid;`
And then: `const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(databaseRef, UID));`
And now I've got an ERROR:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')

Comment: I'am using an useEffect hook to run this getData() function. Maybe there is a problem?
` useEffect(() => {

    getData();

  }, []);`

Comment: That sounds like the user isn't logged in (yet) and you may need an auth state listener as shown in the first snippet in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I think he is because I've got a method to add data and everything works fine:
`const addData = () => {
    const authentication = getAuth();

    addDoc(collection(databaseRef, authentication.lastNotifiedUid), {
          code here
    })`