# Fetch Auth User(s) UID from Firebase via server side

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, uid

I am looking to fetch Auth Users UID from Firebase via a web application. Is there any way to do this. I have attached a screenshot of what i want to fetch.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEnwu.png]

Comment: There were already answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352772/is-there-any-way-to-get-firebase-auth-user-uid) and docs [here](https://softauthor.com/firebase-get-user-data-by-uid/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want get UIDs of all the users or you need you user firebase admin sdk https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users.
If you want to know the id of logged in user's details you can firebase client sdk https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users